# Spring MVC 3 handle request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

What is the alternate for this Spring mvc 2 functionality in Spring MVC 3

```
  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController#handleRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
   * javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
   */
  @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring MVC 2.* you map each controller to each URL. But Spring mvc 3 can map many url's in one controller so each mapping function bahves like handlerequest and any check like for session availability will go in each method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testUrl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getDownloadPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
//logic...........................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have Session as one of the argument in your handlesr beside Request/Respnese/Lcoale/InputStream/OutputStream.

Option exist for what you return too.

Have a alook at 
[15.3.2.3 Supported handler method arguments and return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)